# How to provide a C# .Net Web Service without an ‘elementformdefault = “qualified”’ attribute in the WSDL?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl

I’ll provide a web service for a client with a given WSDL. 
Unfortunately I’m not able to tell the serializer to accept unqualified elementForm.

I seek for the way to set the elementFormDefault to either "unqualified" or even "None" to hide it complete

I’ll receive something like

```
<NS:Request>
    <some stuff>…</some stuff>
</NS:Request>
```

But I see no content in my request
Only if I Change the prefix or remove the prefix and change the NS scope by adding a new NS to the request

```
<NS:Request>
  < NS:some stuff>…</ NS:some stuff>
</NS:Request>
```

or

```
< Request xmlns:myNamespace>
   < some stuff>…</some stuff>
</Request>
```

The web service works fine.

Thanks for your support

Comment: Not entirely clear... That WSDL should provide all namespaces etc. How do you generate the (Server?) classes?

Comment: I not generated the classes from the WSDL. I tryed but it failed :-( finally  I made a new web Service and build all methods etc.

Comment: Does someone know where I can get professional Support to build the WS?

Comment: This site doesn't broker for that. But there are tutorials ans walk-throughs enough on the net. Did you find WSDL.EXE already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is a dead question from 2 years ago, I would still like to answer it as this is my first related search result when I encounter the exact same problem.

The WSDL file generated via .asmx?wsdl has an attribute

```
elementFormDefault=qualified
```

within it's schema tag, which forces the clients to add a namespace prefix to all input element if they were to successfully pass their input to server. (If the client ignore the namespace prefix regardless, the server will receive empty request with no input).

Since in my case my client could not generate a qualified soap request no matter what, I have to change on server side.

The way you do it is to add

```
[XmlElement(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
```

in front of every input parameter for every web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string TestMethod(
    [XmlElement(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]string input1,
    [XmlElement(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]int input2)
{
    /***code here****/
}
```

Comment: Sorry for leaving it open for so long time.
This was exactly how I solved it but I forgot to update.