# Webservice, Generating WSDL with elementFormDefault = "Unqualified"

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

we are right now trying to expose a Web Service method to another company. Their demands are that the method is **OneWay** and we need to have the attribute **elementFormDefault = "Unqualified" **.

We don't fully understand the way this works, we are using VS 2010 and we added a new Item called "Web Service". Then we defined our Web Method and build the solution. Everything worked well and the WSDL generated looks good. The only problem is that we always have **elementFormDefault = "Qualified"** no matter how we define our class.

We can make the WSDL generated to indicate that all attributes are unqualified but we always have the element for default defined as qualified...

When our client tries to use our method we receive empty information...

our class to generate the XML is this one, note that the class is a bit messy as we tried multiple solutions:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using WSGerfip.Ws_Tesouraria;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using WSGerfip.Client_IlcrCallback;

namespace WSGerfip
{


    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // CallBack - WebService que a ESPAP chama.
    //            Este WebService CallBack, por sua vez, chama o Web Service da Tesouraria (Ws_NotasCobranca)
    //            Foi necess�rio implementer esta camada no dotnet, porque em Outsystems n�o dava para definir o atributo OneWay
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    [WebService(Namespace = "urn:espap.gerfip.ilcr.v1")]
    //[XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:espap.gerfip.ilcr.v1", IsNullable=true)]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]


    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    //glide.wsdl.schema.UnqualifiedElementFormDefault




    public class CallBackReceita : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay = true)]
        [WebMethod]

        public void RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult(
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] string CorrelationId)
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] int ResultStatus,
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] RegisterLogisticInvoiceResultResult[] Results,
            [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)] WSGerfip.Client_IlcrCallback.Messages[] GeneralMessages)
        {
            //CorrelationId = this.CorrelationId;
             string linhaA_Escrever;
             string path_escrita;
            path_escrita = "c:\\Temp\\Log_Fatura.txt";

            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path_escrita, true, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));

            try
            {

                linhaA_Escrever = "--------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
                linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "Data: " + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine;
                linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "IdCorrela��o: " + CorrelationId + Environment.NewLine;


                //Results = new Result[1];

                linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "0" + Environment.NewLine;

                //Results[0] = new Result();

                linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "00" + Environment.NewLine;

                //Results[] = Results[];

                //Results[0].PDF = new PDF();
                //Results[0].PDF.InvoicePdf = new byte[10000000];

                linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "1" + Environment.NewLine;


                //Ws_Tesouraria.RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult = new Ws_Tesouraria.RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult();

                //RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult.CorrelationId = CorrelationId;
                //RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult.ResultStatus = ResultStatus;
                //RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult.Results = Results;
                //RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult.GeneralMessages = GeneralMessages;



                //linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "Pdf:2 " + Results[0].PDF.InvoicePdfName + Environment.NewLine;

                ////if (Results[0].PDF != null)
                //linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "Pdf:3 " + Results[0].PDF.InvoicePdfName + Environment.NewLine;



                //linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "Pdf4: " + Results[0].PDF.InvoicePdf.Length + Environment.NewLine;

                //linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "2" + Environment.NewLine;


                ////linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "Nr Fatura: " + Results[0].InvoiceResultNumber + Environment.NewLine;

                ////linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "3" + Environment.NewLine;


                //linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "Resultado: " + ResultStatus;

                streamWriter.WriteLine(linhaA_Escrever);

                //Ws_Tesouraria.RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult = new Ws_Tesouraria.RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult();

                //RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult.CorrelationId = CorrelationId;
                //RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult.ResultStatus = ResultStatus;
                //RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult.Results = Results;
                //RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult.GeneralMessages = GeneralMessages;

                //Ws_Tesouraria.WS_NotasCobranca WS = new Ws_Tesouraria.WS_NotasCobranca();

                //WS.RespostaFatura(RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + Environment.NewLine + " Erro: " + ex;
                //streamWriter.WriteLine(linhaA_Escrever);
            }
            finally
            {
                streamWriter.Close();
                streamWriter.Dispose();
            }

        }



        //[SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay = true)]
        //[WebMethod]
        //public void IfcrCallbackInput(string CorrelationId, int ResultStatus, string CompanyCode, int TotalDocumentsToRegister, decimal TotalAmountToRegister, int TotalDocumentsRegistered,
        //    decimal TotalAmountRegistered, int TotalDocumentsWithError, Document2[] DocumentsInformation, IncomeOrdersResult IncomeOrdersResult)
        //{
        //    path_escrita = "c:\\Temp\\Log_Cobranca.txt";

        //    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path_escrita, true, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));

        //    try
        //    {
        //        linhaA_Escrever = "--------------------------------------------------"                                       + Environment.NewLine;
        //        linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "Data: "         + DateTime.Now                                          + Environment.NewLine;
        //        linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "IdCorrela��o: " + CorrelationId                                         + Environment.NewLine;
        //        //linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "Pdf: "          + IncomeOrdersResult.Documents[0].PDF.InvoicePdf.Length + Environment.NewLine;
        //        //linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "Nr Recibo: "    + IncomeOrdersResult.Documents[0].AssignmentNumber      + Environment.NewLine;
        //        linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + "Resultado: "    + ResultStatus;

        //        streamWriter.WriteLine(linhaA_Escrever);


        //        Ws_Tesouraria.IfcrCallbackInput IfcrCallbackInput = new Ws_Tesouraria.IfcrCallbackInput();

        //        IfcrCallbackInput.CorrelationId = CorrelationId;
        //        IfcrCallbackInput.ResultStatus = ResultStatus;
        //        IfcrCallbackInput.IncomeOrdersResult = new IncomeOrdersResult();
        //        IfcrCallbackInput.IncomeOrdersResult.Documents = DocumentsInformation;
        //        IfcrCallbackInput.IncomeOrdersResult = IncomeOrdersResult;

        //        Ws_Tesouraria.WS_NotasCobranca WS = new Ws_Tesouraria.WS_NotasCobranca();

        //        WS.RepostaCobranca(IfcrCallbackInput);
        //    }
        //    catch (Exception ex)
        //    {
        //        linhaA_Escrever = linhaA_Escrever + Environment.NewLine + " Erro: " + ex;
        //        streamWriter.WriteLine(linhaA_Escrever);
        //    }
        //    finally
        //    {
        //        streamWriter.Close();
        //        streamWriter.Dispose();
        //    }
        //}
    }
}
```

and one of the generated WSDL's:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="urn:espap.gerfip.ilcr.v1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:espap.gerfip.ilcr.v1">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:espap.gerfip.ilcr.v1">
<s:element name="RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult">
<s:complexType>
<s:attribute form="unqualified" name="CorrelationId" type="s:string"/>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="RegisterLogisticInvoiceResultSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="CallBackReceitaSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult">
<wsdl:input message="tns:RegisterLogisticInvoiceResultSoapIn"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="CallBackReceitaSoap" type="tns:CallBackReceitaSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:espap.gerfip.ilcr.v1/RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="CallBackReceitaSoap12" type="tns:CallBackReceitaSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult">
<soap12:operation soapAction="urn:espap.gerfip.ilcr.v1/RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="CallBackReceita">
<wsdl:port name="CallBackReceitaSoap" binding="tns:CallBackReceitaSoap">
<soap:address location="http://srvsicofdv/wsgerfip/callbackReceita.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="CallBackReceitaSoap12" binding="tns:CallBackReceitaSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://srvsicofdv/wsgerfip/callbackReceita.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

We kinda tried everyhing and we are not able to find a solution for this... everytime our method is being called we dont have nothing in the input parameters... and when the cliend send us the WSDL that they used to send to our method infact the attributes are there. This is the WSDL the client wants to send to us, so our WSDL must accept this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">SaveLogisticInvoiceResult</a:Action><h:ContextHeader xmlns:h="urn:GeRAP.Services.GSE.ContextHeaderExtension" xmlns="urn:GeRAP.Services.GSE.ContextHeaderExtension" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><BusinessAxis><CompanyCode>5983</CompanyCode><OrganizationalUnit>ADSE</OrganizationalUnit><Entity xsi:nil="true" /><ProcessActivity xsi:nil="true" /><ProcessId xsi:nil="true" /></BusinessAxis><ChannelAxis><ComunicationChannel>www</ComunicationChannel><Security>SSL</Security></ChannelAxis><IdentityAxis><Group xsi:nil="true" /><User>pp\service.pp.adse</User></IdentityAxis><SubscriprionAxis><Application>ADSE</Application><ApplicationContext>ILCR</ApplicationContext></SubscriprionAxis></h:ContextHeader><GseInternalHeader xmlns="urn:eSPap.Services.GSE.Internal" /><dnh0:DynamicChannelHeader xmlns:dnh0="urn:eSPap.Services.GSE.DynamicChannelExtension"><dnh0:CorrelationToken>ILCR_SERVICE.PP.ADSE_5983</dnh0:CorrelationToken></dnh0:DynamicChannelHeader><a:MessageID>urn:uuid:8886fa85-367b-48f5-a37f-232f57376875</a:MessageID><a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://pp-gseb2b.gerall.pt/TimeKeepingCallbacks</a:To></s:Header><s:Body><RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult xmlns="urn:espap.gerfip.ilcr.v1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <CorrelationId xmlns="">1721027</CorrelationId>
  <ResultStatus xmlns="">1</ResultStatus>
  <Results xmlns="">
    <Result>
      <DocumentId>1</DocumentId>
      <SaleOrderResultNumber>3151100234</SaleOrderResultNumber>
      <InvoiceResultNumber>3155000183</InvoiceResultNumber>
      <PDF>
        <InvoicePdfName>DFLOG3155000183201801181901.pdf</InvoicePdfName>
        <InvoicePdf>A BIG SEQUENCE OF BYTES IS HERE BUT I REMOVED FOR TURNING THIS READ FRIENDLY</InvoicePdf>
      </PDF>
      <InvoiceMessages>
        <Message>
          <Type>Warning</Type>
          <Code>MW010</Code>
          <Text>Item 1 - O campo Montante da condição não está preenchido.</Text>
        </Message>
        <Message>
          <Type>Information</Type>
          <Code>MW026</Code>
          <Text>Mensagens Fatura/Ordem Venda</Text>
        </Message>
        <Message>
          <Type>Information</Type>
          <Code>V1311</Code>
          <Text>Ordem standard 3151100234 foi gravado(a)</Text>
        </Message>
        <Message>
          <Type>Information</Type>
          <Code>VF311</Code>
          <Text>Documento 3155000183 foi gravado</Text>
        </Message>
      </InvoiceMessages>
      <TotalValue>55.00</TotalValue>
    </Result>
  </Results>
  <GeneralMessages xmlns="" />
</RegisterLogisticInvoiceResult></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966255/how-to-provide-a-c-sharp-net-web-service-without-an-elementformdefault-qual

Comment: Thanks for the hint but we have already tried it and when I do that it puts the atributes as unqualified like this

<s:attribute **form="unqualified"** name="CorrelationId" type="s:string"/>

but this tag remains wrong:

<s:schema **elementFormDefault="qualified"** targetNamespace="urn:espap.gerfip.ilcr.v1">